# Add a character at the 3rd last position of the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a var with value in digits and i want to add '=' sign at the third last position
such that

```
var num = 98564;
```

would become

```
985=64
```

by googling I came accross this function

```
String.prototype.insert = function (index, string) {
  if (index > 0)
    return this.substring(0, index) + string + this.substring(index, this.length);
  else
    return string + this;
}
```

I think it will do my job, but I also want to keep a condition that
if `var num = 98;` (2 digits) then the output should be `0=98`

can you help me modifying that function? also guide me to do the same in PHP (any inbuilt function that you know?) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PHP

```
function new_num($int) {
    $new_num = (isset($int) ? (strlen($int) > 2 ? substr_replace($int, '=', strlen($int)-2, 0) : '0=' . $int) : null);
    return $new_num;
}

$num = 16000;
$new_num = new_num($num);
```

The function will check that the input is set (although it's a bit redundant in a function seeing as the variable is required, I put it there in case you didn't want it to be a function) and then check if the length of the input is greater than 2. If greater than 2, it will insert the "=", otherwise it will add "0=" to the front. The javascript is doing essentially the same thing but just to note it has to be converted to a string to manipulate it with substring, length, etc.

## Javascript:

```
var num = 16000;
num = num.toString();
if (num.length > 2) {
    var new_num = num.substring(0, num.length-2) + '=' + num.slice(-2);
} else {
    var new_num = '0=' + num;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! but theres a problem for number "16000" I get output as "16=000" where as it should be "160=00"

Comment: Sorry about that. I've replaced the code with corrections. Hopefully that will work for you.